# What output and recording ports does the Java Sound API find on your computer?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I'm working with the [Java Sound API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/), and it turns out if I want to adjust recording volumes I need to model the hardware that the OS exposes to Java. Turns out there's a lot of variety in what's presented.

Because of this I'm humbly asking that anyone able to help me run the following on their computer and post back the results so that I can get an idea of what's out there.

A thanks in advance to anyone that can assist :-)

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
public class SoundAudit {
  public static void main(String[] args) { try {
    System.out.println("OS: "+System.getProperty("os.name")+" "+
      System.getProperty("os.version")+"/"+
      System.getProperty("os.arch")+"\nJava: "+
      System.getProperty("java.version")+" ("+
      System.getProperty("java.vendor")+")\n");
      for (Mixer.Info thisMixerInfo : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
        System.out.println("Mixer: "+thisMixerInfo.getDescription()+
          " ["+thisMixerInfo.getName()+"]");
        Mixer thisMixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(thisMixerInfo);
        for (Line.Info thisLineInfo:thisMixer.getSourceLineInfo()) {
            if (thisLineInfo.getLineClass().getName().equals(
              "javax.sound.sampled.Port")) {
              Line thisLine = thisMixer.getLine(thisLineInfo);
              thisLine.open();
              System.out.println("  Source Port: "
                +thisLineInfo.toString());
              for (Control thisControl : thisLine.getControls()) {
                System.out.println(AnalyzeControl(thisControl));}
              thisLine.close();}}
        for (Line.Info thisLineInfo:thisMixer.getTargetLineInfo()) {
          if (thisLineInfo.getLineClass().getName().equals(
            "javax.sound.sampled.Port")) {
            Line thisLine = thisMixer.getLine(thisLineInfo);
            thisLine.open();
            System.out.println("  Target Port: "
              +thisLineInfo.toString());
            for (Control thisControl : thisLine.getControls()) {
              System.out.println(AnalyzeControl(thisControl));}
            thisLine.close();}}}
  } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
  public static String AnalyzeControl(Control thisControl) {
    String type = thisControl.getType().toString();
    if (thisControl instanceof BooleanControl) {
      return "    Control: "+type+" (boolean)"; }
    if (thisControl instanceof CompoundControl) {
      System.out.println("    Control: "+type+
        " (compound - values below)");
      String toReturn = "";
      for (Control children:
        ((CompoundControl)thisControl).getMemberControls()) {
        toReturn+="  "+AnalyzeControl(children)+"\n";}
      return toReturn.substring(0, toReturn.length()-1);}
    if (thisControl instanceof EnumControl) {
      return "    Control:"+type+" (enum: "+thisControl.toString()+")";}
    if (thisControl instanceof FloatControl) {
      return "    Control: "+type+" (float: from "+
        ((FloatControl) thisControl).getMinimum()+" to "+
        ((FloatControl) thisControl).getMaximum()+")";}
    return "    Control: unknown type";}
}
```

All the application does is print out a line about the OS, a line about the JVM, and a few lines about the hardware found that may pertain to recording hardware. For example on my PC at work I get the following:

OS: Windows XP 5.1/x86
Java: 1.6.0_07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

```
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Primary Sound Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [SoundMAX HD Audio]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Primary Sound Capture Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [SoundMAX HD Audio]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port SoundMAX HD Audio]
  Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
    Control: Microphone (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Microphone Boost (boolean)
      Control: Front panel microphone (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: LINE_IN source port
    Control: Line In (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
```

Comment: As this is not a right/wrong question (or even a question really), I believe that you may have more success if you change this question to a community wiki.  But even then it may still be closed.  Good luck to ya!

Comment: No "thank-you" vote for the people who went to the trouble of running your code?  Cold, Dave. Cold.  ;)

Comment: Everyone who posts a real response should vote for everyone else who posts.  That would be encouragement.  I'm doing so.

Comment: I'm voting for *anything* that comes in valid - I reely reely appreciate all the feedback - I cannot figure out how to find out stuff like this without forums such as this - this stuff is gold to me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never messed with the sound API--this is a good thing to have seen.  Thanks.

From a [Dell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell) laptop:

```
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Primary Sound Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [SigmaTel Audio]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Primary Sound Capture Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [SigmaTel Audio]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port SigmaTel Audio]
  Source Port: Stereo Mix source port
    Control: Stereo Mix (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: LINE_IN source port
    Control: Line In (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
    Control: Microphone (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Microphone Boost (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
    Control: Microphone (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Microphone Boost (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: SPEAKER target port
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: PC Spk Mute (boolean)
    Control: SPDIF Interface (boolean)
    Control: Wave (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: PC Speaker (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
```

Comment: Would be more useful if you hadn't edited out the OS version

Answer (score 6):

```
OS: Mac OS X 10.5.6/i386
Java: 1.5.0_16 (Apple Inc.)

Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: No details available [Built-in Microphone]
Mixer: No details available [Built-in Input]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
OS: Windows XP 5.1/x86
Java: 1.6.0_12 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Primary Sound Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [SoundMAX Digital Audio]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Primary Sound Capture Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [SoundMAX Digital Audio]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port SoundMAX Digital Audio]
  Source Port: COMPACT_DISC source port
    Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
    Control: Microphone (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: MIC Boost (boolean)
      Control: Mic2 Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: Aux source port
    Control: Aux (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: LINE_IN source port
    Control: Line In (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: Phone source port
    Control: Phone (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: Mono Out source port
    Control: Mono Out (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: Wave Out Mix source port
    Control: Wave Out Mix (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: SPEAKER target port
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
    Control: AC3 SPDIF (boolean)
    Control: PCM SPDIF (boolean)
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Wave (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: BassBoost (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Microphone (compound - values below)
      Control: Mic2 Select (boolean)
      Control: MIC Boost (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Aux (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Line In (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Phone (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Mono Out (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
```

---

Note: copied from http://fnord.pastebin.ca/1341281

Answer (score 5):

As Uri noted, the Java Sound API definitely does not produce any interesting results on Mac OS X:

```
OS: Darwin 9.6.0/i386
Java: 1.6.0_03-p3 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Mixer: software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
```

Also, I should note that I'm using soylatte-1.0.3 rather than the rather elderly JDK distributed with Apple's developer tools.

Answer (score 5):

```
asus p5gc-mx/1333

Name    Realtek High Definition Audio
Manufacturer    Realtek
Status  OK
PNP Device ID   HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0662&SUBSYS_10438290&REV_1001\4&18A64267&0&0001
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\rtkhdaud.sys (5.10.0.5506 built by: WinDDK, 4.41 MB (4,620,288 bytes), 12/23/2008 5:14 PM)


OS: Windows XP 5.1/x86
Java: 1.6.0_11 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Primary Sound Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Realtek HD Audio output]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Primary Sound Capture Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Realtek HD Audio Input]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port Realtek HD Audio output]
  Target Port: SPEAKER target port
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Wave (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Front (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Rear (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Subwoofer (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Center (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: SPDIF (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Line Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Mic Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Microphone Boost (boolean)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: CD Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port Realtek HD Audio Input]
  Source Port: COMPACT_DISC source port
    Control: CD Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Source Port: LINE_IN source port
    Control: Line Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
    Control: Mic Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Source Port: Stereo Mix source port
    Control: Stereo Mix (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Recording Control target port
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: CD Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Line Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Mic Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Stereo Mix (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
OS: Linux 2.6.24-23-generic/amd64
Java: 1.6.0_05 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Mixer: Direct Audio Device: NVidia CK804, Intel ICH, NVidia CK804 [CK804 [plughw:0,0]]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: NVidia CK804, Intel ICH - MIC ADC, NVidia CK804 - MIC ADC [CK804 [plughw:0,1]]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: NVidia CK804, Intel ICH - IEC958, NVidia CK804 - IEC958 [CK804 [plughw:0,2]]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: NVidia CK804, Realtek ALC850 rev 0 [Port CK804 [hw:0]]
  Source Port: IEC958 Playback AC97-SPSA source port
    Control: IEC958 Playback AC97-SPSA (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: Capture source port
    Control: Capture (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Select (boolean)
  Target Port: Master target port
    Control: Master (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Master Mono target port
    Control: Master Mono (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: PCM target port
    Control: PCM (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Surround target port
    Control: Surround (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Center target port
    Control: Center (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: LFE target port
    Control: LFE (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Line target port
    Control: Line (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: CD target port
    Control: CD (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Mic target port
    Control: Mic (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Phone target port
    Control: Phone (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: IEC958 Playback AC97-SPSA target port
    Control: IEC958 Playback AC97-SPSA (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: PC Speaker target port
    Control: PC Speaker (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Aux target port
    Control: Aux (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
OS: Windows XP 5.1/x86  
Java: 1.6.0_06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)  

Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Primary Sound Driver]  
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [SoundMAX HD Audio]  
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Primary Sound Capture Driver]  
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [SoundMAX HD Audio]  
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]  
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port SoundMAX HD Audio]  
  Source Port: Stereo Mix source port  
    Control: Stereo Mix (compound - values below)  
      Control: Select (boolean)  
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)  
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)  
  Source Port: MICROPHONE source port  
    Control: Microphone (compound - values below)  
      Control: Select (boolean)  
      Control: Microphone Boost (boolean)  
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)  
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)  
  Source Port: COMPACT_DISC source port  
    Control: CD Player (compound - values below)  
      Control: Select (boolean)  
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)  
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)  
  Target Port: SPEAKER target port  
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)  
    Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)  
    Control: Mute (boolean)  
    Control: Disable Digital Output (boolean)  
    Control: Wave (compound - values below)  
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)  
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)  
      Control: Mute (boolean)  
    Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)  
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)  
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)  
      Control: Mute (boolean)  
    Control: Microphone (compound - values below)  
      Control: Microphone Boost (boolean)  
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)  
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)  
      Control: Mute (boolean)  
    Control: CD Player (compound - values below)  
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)  
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)  
      Control: Mute (boolean)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
OS: Windows XP 5.1/x86
Java: 1.6.0_12 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Primary Sound Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [VIA AC'97 Audio (WAVE)]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Primary Sound Capture Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [VIA AC'97 Audio (WAVE)]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port VIA AC'97 Audio (WAVE)]
  Port: Stereo Mixer source port
    Control: Stereo Mixer (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Port: MICROPHONE source port
    Control: Mic (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Mic2 Select (boolean)
      Control: 20dB boost (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Port: LINE\_IN source port
    Control: Line In (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Port: COMPACT\_DISC source port
    Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Port: Video source port
    Control: Video (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Port: Aux source port
    Control: Aux (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
OS: Windows XP 5.1/x86
Java: 1.6.0_03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Primary Sound Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [SoundMAX HD Audio]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Primary Sound Capture Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [SoundMAX HD Audio]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port SoundMAX HD Audio]
  Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
    Control: Microphone (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Microphone Boost (boolean)
      Control: Front panel microphone (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: LINE_IN source port
    Control: Line In (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: SPEAKER target port
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Wave (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Input Monitor (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
```

Comment: this looks the same as what I have for my work PC (mentioned in the posting) only I listed source ports, & ignored the speaker, sine I'm only interested in line in info ...

Answer (score 3):

```
OS: Linux 2.6.28-15-generic/amd64
Java: 1.6.0_14 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Mixer: Direct Audio Device: HDA Intel, AD198x Analog, AD198x Analog [Intel [plughw:0,0]]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: HDA Intel, AD198x Digital, AD198x Digital [Intel [plughw:0,1]]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: USB Device 0x46d:0x8d7, USB Audio, USB Audio [U0x46d0x8d7 [plughw:1,0]]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: HDA Intel, Analog Devices AD1988 [Port Intel [hw:0]]
  Source Port: Front Mic Boost source port
    Control: Front Mic Boost (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: Mic Boost source port
    Control: Mic Boost (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: IEC958 source port
    Control: IEC958 (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Select (boolean)
  Source Port: Capture source port
    Control: Capture (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Select (boolean)
  Source Port: Capture source port
    Control: Capture (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Select (boolean)
  Source Port: Capture source port
    Control: Capture (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Select (boolean)
  Source Port: Digital source port
    Control: Digital (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: Master target port
    Control: Master (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: PCM target port
    Control: PCM (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: Front target port
    Control: Front (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Front Mic target port
    Control: Front Mic (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Front Mic Boost target port
    Control: Front Mic Boost (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: Surround target port
    Control: Surround (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Center target port
    Control: Center (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: LFE target port
    Control: LFE (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Side target port
    Control: Side (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Line target port
    Control: Line (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: CD target port
    Control: CD (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Mic target port
    Control: Mic (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Mic Boost target port
    Control: Mic Boost (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: IEC958 target port
    Control: IEC958 (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Analog Mix target port
    Control: Analog Mix (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Beep target port
    Control: Beep (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
Mixer: USB Device 0x46d:0x8d7, USB Mixer [Port U0x46d0x8d7 [hw:1]]
  Source Port: Mic source port
    Control: Mic (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Select (boolean)
```

Answer (score 3):

Dell 9150 with Windows 7:

```
OS: Windows 7 6.1/x86
Java: 1.6.0_16 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Primary Sound Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port Speakers (High Definition Audio]
  Target Port: SPEAKER target port
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: CD Audio (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Master Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
```

Comment: Interesting - no DirectSound capture.  Have you disabled it in the Control Panel?

Answer (score 3):

This one is from a MacBook Pro MB990BZ running Windows (pt-BR) on Virtual Box:

```
OS: Windows XP 5.1/x86
Java: 1.6.0_22 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Driver de som primário]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Intel(r) Integrated Audio]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Driver de captura de som primár
io]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Intel(r) Integrated Audio]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port Intel(r) Integrated Audio]
  Source Port: Mixagem estéreo source port
    Control: Mixagem estéreo (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: Mixagem mono source port
    Control: Mixagem mono (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: Auxiliar source port
    Control: Auxiliar (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: Vídeo source port
    Control: Vídeo (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: COMPACT_DISC source port
    Control: Áudio CD (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: LINE_IN source port
    Control: Entrada (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
    Control: Microfone (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Aumento de sensibilidade do microfone (boolean)
      Control: Microfone alternativo (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: Linha de telefone source port
    Control: Linha de telefone (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: SPEAKER target port
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Som wave (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Sint. de SW (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Auxiliar (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Vídeo (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Áudio CD (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Entrada (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Microfone (compound - values below)
      Control: Microfone alternativo (boolean)
      Control: Aumento de sensibilidade do microfone (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Linha de telefone (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Alto-falante (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Saída mono target port
    Control: Mixagem mono (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Microfone (compound - values below)
      Control: Aumento de sensibilidade do microfone (boolean)
      Control: Microfone alternativo (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the Java Sound API isn't implemented correctly on Mac OS X.

Comment: Please add a link, e.g. to a blog post explaining what is missing

Answer (score 2):

Seems to have a problem with GrowlSafari - don't know why this would be registered as an input server...

```
OS: Mac OS X 10.6.1/x86_64
Java: 1.6.0_15 (Apple Inc.)

2009-10-07 15:53:56.203 java[5008:1707] Can't open input server /Library/InputManagers/GrowlSafari
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: No details available [Built-in Microphone]
Mixer: No details available [Built-in Input]
```

Answer (score 2):

From an HP laptop put into a dock with a separate audio output on-dock:

```
OS: Windows XP 5.1 build 2600 Service Pack 2/x86
Java: 1.5.0 (IBM Corporation)

Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Primary Sound Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [SoundMAX HD Audio]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [ATI HD Audio rear output]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Primary Sound Capture Driver]
Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [SoundMAX HD Audio]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port SoundMAX HD Audio]
  Source Port: Stereo Mix source port
    Control: Stereo Mix (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
    Control: Microphone (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Microphone Boost (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Source Port: LINE_IN source port
    Control: Line In (compound - values below)
      Control: Select (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: SPEAKER target port
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Disable digital output (boolean)
    Control: Wave (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: PC Beep (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Line In (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port ATI HD Audio rear output]
  Target Port: SPEAKER target port
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Wave (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
```

Answer (score 2):

I plugged in some of my extra USB sound cards for ya:

```
    OS: Windows XP 5.1/x86
    Java: 1.6.0_13 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Primary Sound Driver]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [C-Media USB Audio Device   ]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [SigmaTel Audio]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [Virtual Cable 1]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [SpeechMikeII]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback [PowerMicII-NS]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Primary Sound Capture Driver]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [C-Media USB Audio Device   ]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [SigmaTel Audio]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Virtual Cable 1]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [SpeechMikeII]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [Buddy DesktopMic PTT]
    Mixer: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture [PowerMicII-NS]
    Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
    Mixer: Port Mixer [Port C-Media USB Audio Device   ]
      Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
      Target Port: SPEAKER target port
        Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
        Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
        Control: Wave (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
      Target Port: Wave In target port
        Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
        Control: AGC (boolean)
    Mixer: Port Mixer [Port SigmaTel Audio]
      Source Port: Stereo Mix source port
        Control: Stereo Mix (compound - values below)
          Control: Select (boolean)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Source Port: LINE_IN source port
        Control: Line In (compound - values below)
          Control: Select (boolean)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
        Control: External Mic (compound - values below)
          Control: Select (boolean)
          Control: Microphone Boost (boolean)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
        Control: External Mic (compound - values below)
          Control: Select (boolean)
          Control: Microphone Boost (boolean)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Target Port: SPEAKER target port
        Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
        Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
        Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: PC Spk Mute (boolean)
        Control: SPDIF Interface (boolean)
        Control: Wave (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
    Mixer: Port Mixer [Port Virtual Cable 1]
      Source Port: SPDIF Interface source port
        Control: SPDIF Interface (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
      Source Port: LINE_IN source port
        Control: Line (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
      Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
        Control: Microphone (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
      Target Port: SPEAKER target port
        Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
        Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
        Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: Wave (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
    Mixer: Port Mixer [Port SpeechMikeII]
      Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
      Target Port: SPEAKER target port
        Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
        Control: Wave (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
      Target Port: Wave In target port
        Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Mixer: Port Mixer [Port Buddy DesktopMic PTT]
      Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
        Control: Microphone (compound - values below)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Mixer: Port Mixer [Port PowerMicII-NS]
      Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
        Control: Microphone (compound - values below)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Target Port: SPEAKER target port
        Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
        Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
        Control: Wave (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: SW Synth (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
        Control: CD Player (compound - values below)
          Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
          Control: Mute (boolean)
```

Comment: this is reely awesome - thx :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
OS: Mac OS X 10.6.7/x86_64
Java: 1.6.0_26 (Apple Inc.)

Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: No details available [Microphone (Pink Front)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OS: Linux 2.6.32-26-generic/i386
Java: 1.6.0_22 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Mixer: Direct Audio Device: HDA Intel, ALC262 Analog, ALC262 Analog [Intel [plughw:0,0]]
Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: HDA Intel, Realtek ALC262 [Port Intel [hw:0]]
  Source Port: Capture source port
    Control: Capture (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Select (boolean)
  Source Port: Capture source port
    Control: Capture (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Select (boolean)
  Source Port: Capture source port
    Control: Capture (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Select (boolean)
  Source Port: Digital source port
    Control: Digital (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: Master target port
    Control: Master (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: PCM target port
    Control: PCM (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: Mic target port
    Control: Mic (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: Beep target port
    Control: Beep (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
  Target Port: ATAPI Mic target port
    Control: ATAPI Mic (compound - values below)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Balance (float: from -1.0 to 1.0)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OS: Windows 7 6.1/amd64
Java: 1.6.0_21 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Mixer: Software mixer and synthesizer [Java Sound Audio Engine]
Mixer: No details available [Microsoft Sound Mapper]
Mixer: No details available [Microphone (Logitech Mic (Orbit]
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port Speakers (High Definition Audio]
  Target Port: SPEAKER target port
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: CD Audio (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Master Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De]
  Target Port: Master Volume target port
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: CD Audio (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Master Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De]
  Target Port: Master Volume target port
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: CD Audio (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Master Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
Mixer: Port Mixer [Port Microphone (Logitech Mic (Orbit]
  Source Port: MICROPHONE source port
    Control: Master Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
  Target Port: Master Volume target port
    Control: Mute (boolean)
    Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
    Control: Master Volume (compound - values below)
      Control: Mute (boolean)
      Control: Volume (float: from 0.0 to 1.0)
```