# Java Sound API - how to get microphone device info?

Tags: java, linux, audio-recording, javasound

I watched the [sound from microphone recording example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3756179/4336130) and, as I can see it, the output seems doesn't show the *currently available microphone device only* info; As a fact, there maybe be another (not a build-in) microphone device available if a headset is plugged for example :)

**EDIT**:
In case of linux I have pulse audio and it shows my notebook build-in microphone as *"Build-in Audio Analog Stereo"* (see image)
[image]

**EDIT**
For example if I run the applet [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585699/list-of-useful-environment-settings-in-java/7616206#7616206) in my NetBeans IDE 8.0.1 JDK 1.7 (linux x64) I am not sure I can see my build-in microphone device in the tree (see image) but still I can record audio with [Sound API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html)
[image]

So my question is... how to get currently **available input device** info like brand (lets say "Logitech" or the native one as "built-in microphone") etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [**Media** example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616206/418556) for a tree of media related properties.

[image]

See the code that makes it for the sources of the data.

Comment: Thank you; The applet code is quite interesting; But still I am bit confused of how to get the "Microphone" data as in the tree like "Front Mic ( 2-VIA High Definition...)"? I have notebook a build in microphone but running the code I don't see any microphone info as the Pulse Audio shows for example? I edited my question; So please give me a tip

Comment: I am confused.  Did you run the code?  Did your microphone appear in there?

Comment: I am not sure; So please see the applet screenshot I attach to my question; As I can get it, I don't see my build-in microphone in the tree; Anyways maybe the input device has another identification in case of java?

Comment: I am still not sure exactly how to get the microphone device info but maybe I am looking wrong place; Please give me a tip

Comment: For example if I use the code http://stackoverflow.com/a/3756179/4336130 I don't see anything similar to "build-in ... analog stereo" so the code doesn't return currently available microphone device info?

Comment: I just found the answer as http://stackoverflow.com/a/562434/4336130 the guy says "the Mac OS doesn't produce any interesting results"... I am wondering cause I have linux so maybe it may have same "uninteresting" results?

Comment: Linux results [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1337032/418556), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/563330/418556).

Comment: That's what I am talking about I can see some kind of similar results on my machine (Linux x64) the mixer lines ; But I don't get it how to get info is the "mixers' list" item as microphone is currently available for example to make possible make it selected etc?